# How do I upload data into a compressed image?

Tags: vulkan

I've recently tried using Block-Compressed image formats in Vulkan and found that when I switch up my code to use a compressed image format, I get a complete garbage image on render.

Using NVIDIA Nsight also shows the same image I see as well.

I uploading the data by copying the raw SRGB pixels to a staging buffer and initiate a vkCmdCopyBufferImage to the target image. I get this output if the `VkImage` and `VkImageView` are of the format: `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_SRGB`
[image]

But when I changed the format to `VK_FORMAT_BC7_SRGB_BLOCK`. I get this image:[image]

I was wondering if I need to do any conversions before copying the data to the image or am I just handling compressed textures wrong

Pastebin for upload code: https://pastebin.com/yrmRrQGp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a compressed image format, you must provide image data that has been compressed in accord with that format. You cannot just change the image format and expect everything to work.